# How to revoke persistent storage in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage, navigator

To make storage in chrome persistent can be achived by [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/persistent-storage):

```
if (navigator.storage && navigator.storage.persist) navigator.storage.persist()
.then(granted => {
    if (granted) console.log("Storage will not be cleared except by explicit user action");
    else console.log("Storage may be cleared by the UA under storage pressure.");
});
```

BUT HOW TO REMOVE PERSISTANCE programmatically?

Comment: For chrome there is currently no revoke method. For firefox there is through [`navigator.permissions.revoke`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/revoke) but since version 51 it has to be enabled by the user in the browser preferences https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1295877#c0

Comment: crazy. so it looks like https://developers.google.com/ (this site was open while i made this try in the console) can store data now forever on my mac...

Comment: @lutz That's not quite how it works. d.g.com always had the ability to store data on your mac. The only difference is how persistent that data is. Without your permission, chrome could choose to delete the stored data under certain conditions, eg. if your disk space runs low. With your permission, chrome will never choose to delete the stored data. You can of course delete it yourself at any time.